# 'rails c' doesn't work, but 'bundle exec rails console' does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, console

I'm setting up the staging and production server on Ubuntu, deploy with Capistrano. Both server has pretty much the same setup. But for for some reason. I can access console on production server with **rails c produciton**. But when I try to access console on staging server using **rails c staging**

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

The only way to access console on my staging server is to do

```
bundle exec rails console staging
```

On staging

- the rvm seems to be correct, I can see the ruby version I'm using.
- the gemset that the application use is there.
- **the application is running fine**. Just can't access console with 'rails c'

But for some reason, I can't access console with **rails c**. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does the command `rails -v` work?

Comment: No, rails -v doesn't work, same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you didn't install rails globally. First, check your rails version you are currently using by `bundle exec rails -v`. Then, install rails globally by `gem install rails -v <version>`. This should solve your issue.

Run `bundle install` only makes rails available inside bundler. In most cases, this should be enough, because bundler helps prevent headaches of version conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions to understand better the situation...

Have you tried running `bundle install` for the current ruby version set on rvm for that application on that server?

Have you updated the gems for another application/branch? sometimes that happens because the `rails c` command uses the latest gems available and `bundle exec...` locates and uses the gems tied to the Gemfile.lock.
The application should run fine because it uses the gems that the Gemfile.lock has listed.

Comment: Bundle install run fine, I did multiple times. For Ruby, I have only 1 ruby version. Like I said, the application is up and running without any issue but that's because Capistrano run every command with 'bundle exec'.